# Powershell script: List files with specific change date (Amount if possible)

Tags: windows, powershell, server

For license porpuses I try to automate the counting process instead of having to login into every single server, go into directory, search a file name and count the  results based on the change date.

Want I'm aiming for:
Running a powershell script every month that checks the directory "C:\Users" for the file "Outlook.pst" recursively. And then filters the result by change date (one month or newer). Then packing this into an email to send to my inbox.

I'm not sure if that's possible, cause I am fairly new to powershell. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: To make it short: yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: PowerShell has good capabilities to run commands on remote systems. Look for `Invoke-Command`. You will need to use an account that has permission to search all user's directories.

Comment: I've tried it already, my script looks like this (Sorry, I don't know how to format the code):

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Filter *.pst -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-30)}

Not sure if that's a good solution plus I have to get into the Invoke-Command now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

I dont know how to start a ps session on a remote computer, but I think the cmdlet Enter-PSSession will do the trick. Or at least it was the first result while searching for "open remote powershell session". If that does not work use the `Invoke-Command` as suggested by lit to get $outlookFiles as suggested below.

For the rest use this.

```
$outlookFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Outlook.pst" }
```

Now you have all files that have this name. If you are not familiar with the pipe in powershell it redirects all objects it found with the Get-ChildItem to the next pipe section and here the Where-Object will filter the received objects. If the current object ($_) will pass the condition it is returned by the whole command.

Now you can filter these objects again to only include the latest ones with.

```
$latestDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
$newFiles = $outlookFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -gt $latestDate }
```

Now you have all the data you want in one object. Now you only have to format this how you like it e.g. you could use `$mailBody = $newFiles | Out-String` and then use `Send-MailMessage -To x@y.z -From r@g.b -Body $mailBody`to send the mail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not as difficult as I thought. The script now looks like this: $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Filter *.pst -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-30)}
$mailBody = $Files | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -To x@y.z -From sender@domain.com -Subject "Testing" -SmtpServer mail.domain.com -Body $mailBody